# Is any $m$-dimensional strict vector subspeace (so $m<p$) a rotational image of the Euclidean subspace $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^p$ of dimension $m$, where $p < m$. I'm checking with you if there alawys exists a rotation $A \in O(p)$ so that $A(V) = \mathbb{R}^p \times \{0\}^{p-m}$, i.e. $V$ is the rotational image of a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^p$ .

**I think the answer is yes, by the following argument, could you please check this?**

Let $V$ be the span of the orthonormal basis $\{v_1,...v_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^p$. It's enough to show that there exists $A \in SO(p)$ so that $< Av_i , e_j> = 0  \forall   m+1 \leq j \leq p$. Solving this for $A$ is basically solving $m(p-m)$ equations. But since $m(p-m) \leq \frac{p^2}{4} \leq \frac{p(p-1)}{2} = dim(O(p))$  as a manifold. So we can always solve for $A \in O(p)$ so that the above equations hold, or equivalently, there exists an $A \in O(p)$ so that $A(V) = \mathbb{R}^p \times \{0\}^{p-m}$.

**Is the above correct?**

Comment: How did you get $\frac{p^2}4$?

Comment: Instead, simply pick an orthonormal basis $v_1,\dots, v_m$ of $V$ and extend it to an orthonormal basis $v_1,\dots, v_p$ of $\Bbb R^p$, then simply map $e_i\mapsto v_i$.

Comment: @Berci thanks!! $m(p-m) = mp - m^2 = p^2/4 - (m - p/2)^2 \leq p^2/4$.

Comment: Nice. Can you spell out the argument about the dimension of the manifold and the solution of the equations?

Comment: Thanks! The point is we're solving $m(p-m)$ linear equations for the coefficients of $A$, i.e. solving for $p(p-1)/2$ unknowns with  $ m(p-m)$ constraints, so the solution exist in the orthogonal group, since it has dimension  $p(p-1)/2 > m(p-m)$. But my concern is: this part is missing a logic, as the orthogonal matrices are the solutions to a set of quadratic (not linear) equations...

Comment: Hint: Find an orthonormal basis in $V$ and complete it to an orthonormal basis in $R^n$.

Comment: The trouble with the "dimension count" that you are using is that you are imposing linear conditions on a non-linear subset of the space of all matrices (namely, on $O(p)$). If you were to do so in ${\mathbb C}^n$ and your nonlinear subset given by some polynomial equations, then indeed, you can prove existence of a solution this way (with some caveats).  But when you work with real numbers, this method fails. For instance, consider the single linear condition $x_1=2$ imposed on the unit sphere, $\{x: x_1^2+...+x_n^2=1\}$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes that's a pretty valid argument, trying to apply linear constraints on a non-linear subset (manifold), thanks for that!